# xnview lags when I start it

Tags: windows-7

When I open xnView, the application freezes for like 15-20 seconds, after which works.

What could be the problem?
This only started happening a few days ago, out of the blue...

Comment: what is it opening up to? Doesnt XnView come to life with the thumbnails of the directory already showing? Check the I/O on it with task manager or resources monitor and see if it is working first then showing its window. I am going to be using xnview, I am interested.

Comment: Does this happen when starting with whatever directory being displayed ? Have you tried to delete all your favorite directories ?

Comment: No, it happens with any directory or file I open. I don't have favorite directories.

Comment: Is it possible that the disk went to sleep? or any disk involved in the process.  AKA does it happen on second run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely it is trying to access a network resource and can't find it. Usually because the server it's on isn't responding or no longer exists. Timing it more accurately can help troubleshooting as the delay will always be over the timeout value.

Try and see what it is trying to open or access. I would suggesting using Sysinternals  [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb896645) and/or [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb896653).

A 15 second delay is often from trying to access an IP address that doesn't respond but should be reachable. You can use Sysinternals [TCPView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb897437) to see what address it's trying to access (open a connection to).

Answer (score 2):

Now I have found the reason why and answer myself - just for the case somebody stumbles upon this issue.
Today I have inspected my Windows Media Center setup and found out that I had configured the libraries for my old Raspberry. As soon as I had removed the old entries and replaced them with the new ones the issue went away.
So in short: XNView also seems to look into the folders configured for the WindowsMediaCenter.
When there are issues with slow start you maybe have configured fileshares on a host which do nomore exist.

Answer (score 0):

Just fixed this issue myself. It was a dead shortcut located in the same folder. I got NO idea why this was an issue. But it's fixed